# Sklearn LinearRegression is returning incorrect correlation coefficient

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I created a function that calculates linear regression for multiple columns in my dataframe, but the correlation coef it returns is incorrect

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_csv("Wine_RegionColor.csv")

def linear_regression_calc(): 

  variables = df.columns[0:10]
  correlations = {}

   for var in variables:
    
    #define x and y
    X = df['quality']
    y = df[var]
    
    #reshape x 
    X_reshape = X.values.reshape(-1,1)
    y_reshape = y.values.reshape(-1,1)
    
    #fit model
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(X_reshape, y_reshape)
    
    
    y_pred = model.predict(X_reshape)
    
    #plot
    plt.scatter(X_reshape, y_reshape)
    plt.plot(X_reshape, y_pred, color='red')
    plt.ylabel(var)
    plt.xlabel("Quality")
    plt.legend(model.coef_)
    plt.show()
    
    #append variable and correlation coef to "correlations" dict
    correlations[var] = model.coef_
    
  return correlations
linear_regression_calc()
```

Output:

```
{'fixed_acidity': array([[-0.0471773]]),
 'volatile_acidity': array([[-0.01104745]]),
 'citric_acid': array([[0.00325178]]),
 'residual_sugar': array([[-0.76241198]]),
 'chlorides': array([[-0.00353463]]),
 'free_sulfur_dioxide': array([[-0.23074755]]),
 'total_sulfur_dioxide': array([[-8.95033594]]),
 'density': array([[-0.19647623]]),
 'pH': array([[0.01551016]]),
 'sulphates': array([[0.00305494]])}
```

I tried to reshape the x and y a few different ways but it always returned the same correlation coef

Comment: Who's says they are incorrect and why? [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 0):

model.coef_ is not giving you the correlation but the slope of the linear fit.
Try reading up on [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)